# Problems installing vcpkg for visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, vcpkg

When I try to start bootstrap-vcpkg.bat it doesn't build anything,
instead I get this messagge

```
PS C:\dev\vcpkg> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
Downloading https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/2021-02-24/vcpkg.exe -> C:\dev\vcpkg/vcpkg.exe
Done.
Telemetry
---------
vcpkg collects usage data in order to help us improve your experience.
The data collected by Microsoft is anonymous.
You can opt-out of telemetry by re-running the bootstrap-vcpkg script with -disableMetrics,
passing --disable-metrics to vcpkg on the command line,
or by setting the VCPKG_DISABLE_METRICS environment variable.
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Do you have any kind of software that can interfere with it? Like an anti virus or firewall?

Comment: Thx for answering

No I don't think I have something that can interfere with it.
I tried multiple times to install it, but never worked.

I'm really a nebie with this thing.

Comment: I think you'd have more luck with opening an issue on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing went wrong. As you can see at the top of the Message, the latest version of the vcpkg executable was downloaded from github.

> Downloading https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/2021-02-24/vcpkg.exe -> C:\dev\vcpkg/vcpkg.exe
> Done.

The rest of the Message is just the usual disclaimer about metrics (and it tells you how to disable them if you want)